# Deep copy of linear linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, deep-copy

I have a linear linked list that consists of nodes:

```
class Node{
    Object data;
    Node link;

    public Node(Object pData, Node pLink){
        this.data = pData;
        this.link = pLink;
    }

    public String toString(){
        if(this.link != null){
            return this.data.toString() + this.link.toString();
        }else{
            return this.data.toString() ;
        }
    }

    public void inc(){
        this.data = new Integer((Integer)this.data + 1);
    }

    public Node copy(){
        return new Node(this.data, this.link.copy());
    }
}
```

I want to make a deep copy of a list. Then increment each node of the original list and print both. I do not know if the code is right.

```
class Aufg1{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Node node3 = new Node(new Integer(3), null);            
        Node node2 = new Node(new Integer(2), node3);           
        Node node1 = new Node(new Integer(1), node2);
        System.out.println(node1.copy().toString());
        System.out.println(node1.toString());
    }
}
```

...gives me just 123 for the second println but something is wrong with the copy. Any ideas?

Update:

```
   public Node copy(){
        if(this.link != null){
            return new Node(new Integer((Integer)this.data), this.link.copy());
        }else{
            return new Node(new Integer((Integer)this.data), null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Even if you're doing a deep copy, don't create a copy of an Integer.  Even a deep copy shouldn't need to copy immutable objects since they intrinsically can be safely shared.  Also, if you know and rely on `data` being an Integer, why not declare it as such?

Comment: thanks, I change that integer thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A deep copy would imply that you need to do a copy of data also.

```
 public Node copy(){
    return new Node(copy of this.data, this.link.copy());
 }
```

So you need to decide how you are going to copy the object.

EDIT:  You can use something like the [Deep Cloning Library](http://robust-it.co.uk/clone/) to help. They use reflection etc. If you know the type of objects in that you are creating the class of objects yourself you can create a copy constructor.

Comment: well how do I copy the object? calling clone()? sorry but in that case it is not allowed to use deep copy libraries, I have to use basic java methods

Comment: I have updated my question with new code. Is it possible to make a deep copy the way the code shows it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, judging from the fact that link could be null, you may wish to avoid calling this.link.copy() without checking first.  I am guessing the problem you are talking about is a null pointer exception.

EDIT:

Yeah, and what Vincent said. :)

Be sure to copy the object as well.